# softkeyboard pushing content outside the screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to add 2 buttons to the bottom of the screen.
I can't add any layout at the bottom in scrollview, so I created 2 different layouts.
But content is going outside of the screen when I open soft keyboard, it also goes out of screen on small screen devices (like 4 inch device).

This is the layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/op"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".accept"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="60dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="128dp">

                <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/appname"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/home" />

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frameLayout4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <EditText

                        android:id="@+id/vno"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="true"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:focusedByDefault="true"
                        android:hint="MH14DD2565"
                        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                        android:maxLength="10"

                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.395" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/vvno"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="43dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:hint="MH14DD2565"
                        android:nextFocusUp="@id/location"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="Enter Vehicle Number:"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/location"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="nigdi"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:onClick="display"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.848" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/vaname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:text="Enter Location:"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.613" />


                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="165dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Submit"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="display"
                        android:text="submit" />

                </FrameLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Register"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cp"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:onClick="callp"
                android:text="call 100"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ch"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:onClick="callhos"
                android:text="Call 108" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use ScrollView as parent of your layout

Comment: Post the screenshot of the UI